# The Number of the Feast

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, seasonal, regional-dialects

*The feast is prepared, its scent rich and sweet,

so pull up a chair and bon appetit!*

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer is:

> HAPPY THANKSGIVING!
>  I guess it's on everyone's minds...

Solution:

> Note the colored items on the lego table:

> Yellowish green: SQUASH
>  Dark brown: GRAVY
>  White: MASHEDPOTATOES
>  Orange: PUMPKIN
>  Yellow: TURKEY
>  Dark Green: WINE

> And use the colored number tiles to index into them:

> SQUASH (6) = H
>  GRAVY (3) = A
>  MASHEDPOTATOES (7) = P
>  PUMPKIN (4) = P
>  TURKEY (6) = Y
>  TURKEY (1) = T
>  MASHEDPOTATOES (4) = H
>  SQUASH (4) = A
>  WINE (3) = N
>  TURKEY (4) = K
>  SQUASH (1) = S
>  GRAVY (1) = G
>  PUMPKIN (6) = I
>  GRAVY (4) = V
>  WINE (2) = I
>  PUMPKIN (7) = N
>  GRAVY (1) = G

Op provided a visual:

> [image: answer]